# Density of states for a 1D Fermi gas in the gravitational field

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential, fermions, density-of-states

We are considering a 1D Fermi gas in a gravitational field. The energy levels are given as $E_n = mgh_0n^{2/3}$ and we are asked to calculate the density of states $D(E)$ for the case that $E_0=mgh_0 \to 0$, which I understand as the energy levels becoming continuous with n.

I started by expressing my n in terms of the energy

$n(E)=(\frac{E}{mgh_0})^{\frac{3}{2}}$, and then rewrote my expression for the density of states as follows:

$D(E)=\frac{dN}{dE}=\frac{dN}{dn}\frac{dn}{dE}$

The first term equals 2 because of the 2 fermions that can occupy each state. The second term is just the derivative of n(E) and hence my overall density of states computes to:

$D(E)=3(mgh_0)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{E} \propto \sqrt{E}$

However, in my class we last discussed the fact that for one-dimensional problems you usually see that $D(E) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}$. Why do I not get this behaviour in my case? Did I calculate it incorrectly? Any help is appreciated! Thank you.